# When initing an object autorelease is used. But release later called on object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My project uses the oauthconsumer code in it.

When I am compiling and analising my code I get a noticed about an 'Object sent- autorelease too many times'.

It would be a fair assumption to make the code was written by a lot better engineer than me so I hesitate to 'fix' it.

Is the following code wrong?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    OAServiceTicket *ticket = [[OAServiceTicket alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                              response:response
                                                                  data:responseData
                                                            didSucceed:[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] < 400];
    [ticket autorelease]; // HERE
    [delegate performSelector:didFinishSelector withObject:ticket withObject:responseData];
    [ticket release], ticket = nil; //HERE
}
```

Is that good code or should the auto release get removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the autorelease and you'll be fine. The better engineer clearly made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario shown, since `ticket` is being explicitly released and not returned from the method, there's no reason to add it to the autorelease pool and the `autorelease` call can be safely removed.